# Inductive Logic on Existence

Tags: logic, consciousness

Because we, only by inductive reasoning, are sure about next moment 'happening' (or more precisely, not worried about it *not* happening), does this mean that there is no *logical guarantee* that next moment (universe, consciousness, existence or perhaps anything we can perceive) will certainly happen?

Comment: There are a least two definitions of "induction". Which one are you refering to? If I understand correctly you are basically asking for a justification of the correctness of induction?

Comment: Everything is a probability. The Sun is very probably going to continue producing heat for billions of years. Largely because there is very little which can stop it. Whether an individual will be alive tomorrow is much less probable. Knowing more about the factors involved in any event, increases one's ability to predict.

Comment: Isn't there kind of a guarantee that  the next moment eventually won't happen?  How would induction deal with that?  Induction, in general, is not a useful concept.  We presume 'ceteris paribus, status quo' -- unless something happens, things will not change.  This is not based on experience, it is just the fallback position you have to take unless you know something.  What we think of as induction is just tempering hasty generalization with appropriate skepticism.

Comment: We are **not** sure about anything, period.

Comment: we are sure that something will happen: a new instant or the end of time.

Comment: @Mauro Are you being ironic? How can you be sure?

Answer (score -2):

there is no guarantee that the previous moment happened (you could have just spawned will implanted memories), or that the next will happen (it's just unseen and therefore unlikely).

There is no guarantee either that time flows from past to future. We could be in a sort of movie watched in reverse and would have no way of knowing it. The movie tape analogy helps with these time issues.

Comment: Can you revise the first sentence?

Comment: Not really, "there is no guarantee that the previous moment happened," is a contradiction in terms. Plus, proposing that "previous moment" was merely an implant does not imply it did not happen. In fact, it did happen, precisely, as an implant.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I dont see the contradiction in terms, please elaborate. In the spawning case, the previous moment didnt happen *for you* cause you didnt exist at that moment. It didnt exist as you think it did either. It may not exist at all if the entire universe was spawned.

Comment: @MarkAndrews I added parenthesis, if that was the issue